# How can I mirror a few specific rows from one sheet to another sheet in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

That's simple i know that =Sheet1!B2 but if i add row above the B2. formulas automatically change to B3. I can write code google apps script but i need to do it with formula. By the way add row automatically specific time.
[image: Presentation to whats happen]

I want it to stay constant B2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my testing it would be:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!B2")*K2
```

The "Indirect" function returns a cell reference by a string, so the helpful google sheets can't change it by adding new rows.

Comment: It's simple. I missed it. Thank you.